# HTML- Required "bug"

Tags: html, required

I was working on an html registration form, and i discovered, that if you have, the form fields, for example, the login field, email field, ecc.. and you put on the `<input> </input>` the `required` attribute, if for example someone right click on the screen and click analyze element (for example in firefox), he will able to change the html and obiviusoly delete, the `required` attribure.
My question is: is there a method to avoid that this attribure be deleted?

Comment: You can never trust anything from the client.  You must validate on the server.

Comment: Get the input value from your form and validate those values at your server side and update to clients side accordingly

Comment: HTML and js validation is mearly meant to stop the user from inputting incorrect data. Basically  to make normal users follow the correct procedures for data entry. Using a server sided language like PHP you'll be able to validate at your end and stop incorrect submissions from being processed.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88779/how-to-prevent-user-from-removing-disabled-attribute-and-manually-editing-role